# Translating a json dataset to different natural language

Tags: python, json, machine-learning, nlp, dataset

I have a very big JSON dataset of conversations in the English language, and I would like to ask if there is any tool or way that can translate them from English to the Arabic language?

Comment: Try https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a google translate package for python. https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/

You can read the json file in python and then translate every sentence one by one. Later if you want you can save it again as json.

Assuming you have a function called "translate"(wrapper function using the library) that translates one data point in english to arabic. Something like this is what you need.

```
with open(data_json_path, 'r') as f:
    data_json = json.load(f)

english_as_list = [sample['text'] for sample in data_json]
arabic = [translate(sample) for sample in english_as_list]
```